# I need to update the value in the table base on id match in WHERE IN claus

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have array of data like below:

```
$data = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 29
            [value_1] => 1
            [value_2] => 1
            [value_3] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 116
            [value_1] => 1
            [value_2] => 1
            [value_3] => 1
        )

)
```

and i have to update it like in update query where in the id matched then set the only particular values for that.
suppose my query like this

```
update table set value1 = $data[matched_id_index]['value_1'],value2 = $data[matched_id_index]['value_2'],value3 = $data[matched_id_index]['value_3'] where id in (data[0]['id'],$data[1]['id]);
```

Means basically i need to update the matched id value for particular column.

Comment: you cannot update using WHERE IN. run separate queries for each array

Comment: done with this but takes long time to update through multiple queries

Comment: so you had to ask exactly that question

Comment: It working fine with inserting data but while updating take too much long time and we have to update thousands of records and we are also using the primary for better performs but things seems hopeless

Comment: updating thousands of records takes a fraction of second